# I want to return a property in an object in an array but its causing other problems in the code

Tags: javascript, function, object, p5.js

So I'm using this function that's supposed to make a car change lanes. It will change lanes as long as I don't return the number plate `return vehicleObject_list[i]`. But when I return the number plate as the instructions ask, the car stops changing lanes `return vehicleObject_list[i].Number_Plate`. The details are below:

```js
function moveLanes(target_car)
{
    /*
    This function should do the following: 
     - move target_car from one lane to the other.
     - do the move in a single step without any extra animation.
     - use Lane_Position_a and Lane_Position_b to effect the change.
     - finally you should return target_car at the end of the function.
     hint: You will need to modify the x property of target_car.
    */
    if(checkCarInfront(target_car).x == Lane_Position_a ){
        target_car.x = Lane_Position_b;
    }   
    else {
        target_car.x = Lane_Position_a;
    }
    
}


function checkCarInfront( carObj )
{
    /*
    This function should do the following: 
     - determine if carObj is in the same lane and less than 200px behind any of the cars in vehicleObject_list.
     - do this by traversing vehicleObject_list and comparing each car's Distance_Driven property to that of carObj.
     - if you find a car that matches these requirements then return the Number_Plate property for the car. Otherwise return false.
    */
    
    for (var i = 0; i < vehicleObject_list.length; i++)
    {
        if (carObj.x == vehicleObject_list[i].x && ((vehicleObject_list[i].Distance_Driven - carObj.Distance_Driven) < 200) && ((vehicleObject_list[i].Distance_Driven - carObj.Distance_Driven) > 0))
        {
            return vehicleObject_list[i].Number_Plate;
        }
    }
    return false;
    
    
}

var vehicleObject_list = [
{ x: 500, y: 0, Distance_Driven: -200, Car_Type: 'greenCar', Number_Plate: 'MBH0WW', Gas_Amt: 2, exhaust: [  ]} , { x: 500, y: 0, Distance_Driven: 200, Car_Type: 'whiteCar', Number_Plate: 'RLDGCM', Gas_Amt: 2, exhaust: [  ]} , { x: 300, y: 0, Distance_Driven: 600, Car_Type: 'whiteCar', Number_Plate: '9WGXXI', Gas_Amt: 2, exhaust: [  ]} ]

Detective_CarObject = 
    {
        x: roadLeftEdge + roadWidth/4,
        y: 550,
        Distance_Driven: 0,
        Gas_Amt: 3,
        EngineShudder_Value: 0,
        Car_Type: 'detective',
        Number_Plate: '5L3UTH',
        exhaust: []
    }
```

Comment: `checkCarInfront` returns a `Number_Plate` (or `false`) which most likely doesn't have a `x` property

Comment: Hi @Andreas, thanks for your comment but that is what it says in the instructions. That I must return a number plate or false.

Comment: Yes, but this should tell you that your current logic is wrong. Why do you use the return value of `checkCarInFront` to check the current lane when it's a property of the car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
if(checkCarInfront(target_car) && target_car.x == Lane_Position_a ){
    target_car.x = Lane_Position_b;
} else {
    target_car.x = Lane_Position_a;
}
```

because `checkCarInfront(target_car)` will return a number plate string if there is a match (which will evaluate to true as a non empty string). You can link the condition to the `target_car` object which has an `.x` property.

Be sure to manually test the data. (for example, with the current `vehicleObject_list` and `Detective_CarObject` values if you call `checkCarInfront(Detective_CarObject)` this will be false (due to `Distance_Driven`). You can however temporarily set `Detective_CarObject`'s x to `500` and add an extra test car in the list to check your logic: `{ x: 500, y: 0, Distance_Driven: 199, Car_Type: 'rainbowCar', Number_Plate: 'R41NB0W', Gas_Amt: 2, exhaust: [  ]}`)

As a side note I recommend adhering to JS naming conventions. Here are a couple of examples: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp), [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-naming-conventions-dos-and-don-ts-99c0e2fdd78a/), [Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html).
In the past I would've said choose one (e.g. underscores/snake_case (e.g. `target_cat`) or camelCase (e.g. `checkCarInFront`)) but not both and keep it consistent, but these days it seems the majority adhere to camelCase. Doing so will make it much easier to work in a team later and share/contribute to open source libraries and projects.